# Lazy loading one to many in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am stuck on this problem. Basicly I have one to many relationship between entities `User` and `Book` (User can have many books), two transactional repositories and transactional service. I use JPA with hibernate implementation.

When i try to access list of books which is lazy loaded i get `NullPointerException` and when i enable SQL logs, i notice that sql query is not called. If i change to eager it works as expected.

Here is code that I think is relevant to this problem:

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {
...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =        FetchType.LAZY)
   @JsonIgnore
   private List<Book> rentedBooks;
```

Book.java

```
@Entity
public class Book {
...
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_ID")
    @JsonProperty("user")
    private User user;
```

BookRepository.java

```
@Repository
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.MANDATORY)
public class BookRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    public EntityManager em;
```

UserRepository.java

```
@Repository
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.MANDATORY)
public class UserRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
```

BookService.java

```
@Service
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
public class BookServices {
...
public void rentBook(String bookID, String fbID) {
        if (!userRepository.checkIfUserExists(fbID)) {
            User user = new User(fbID);
            userRepository.addUser(user);
        }
        User user = userRepository.findByUserByFacebookID(fbID);
        Book book = bookRepository.findBookByGoogleBookID(bookID);

        book.setStatus(Status.rented);
        book.setUser(user);
        bookRepository.updateBook(book);

        //user.getRentedBooks() is null
        user.getRentedBooks().add(book);
    }
```

I noticed that if user does not exist and is created `getRentedBooks` is null, but if it was created earlier, `getRentedBooks` is not null and works as expected with lazy loading.

This is my config:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.polarcape" />
    <!--<property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />-->
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `List<Book>` of the `User` object in the `UserService`

```
User user = userRepository.findByUserByFacebookID(fbID);
Hibernate.initialize(user.getRentedBooks()); //Initialize the lazy-loaded collection
Book book = bookRepository.findBookByGoogleBookID(bookID);
```

Quick intro about the need for `Hibernate.initialize()`: (from the documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-initialization))

> A LazyInitializationException will be thrown by Hibernate if an
>   uninitialized collection or proxy is accessed outside of the scope of
>   the Session, i.e., when the entity owning the collection or having the
>   reference to the proxy is in the detached state.

In your case, the `List<Book>` is the uninitialized collection

Comment: My mistake, i forgot to write that i use JPA with hibernate implementation, also isn't Spring supposed to handle initialization of lazy-loaded collections?

Comment: @SarathChandra - shouldnt `getRentedBooks()` do the same in case it is called while still within transaction?

Comment: The exception i get is `NullPointerException`, not `LazyInitializationException`

Comment: @LeetzMKD: As per my understanding, the `user.getRentedBooks()` returns null in case of a newly created `User`, because the `List<Book` attribute it is not an initialized collection and there are no books mapped to the given user. If you initialize it, however, it returns an empty list, to which you can happily add the book.

Answer (score 0):

In a common scenario, after associate `book` with its `user` you must **flush** the changes. Then you just need to *refresh* the `user` instance.

In your case, you could do it too but it will be more programmaticaly correct keep the object model consistent, you should add the `book` to the `user.rentedBooks` collection

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what am I doing, but as i said im getting `NullPointerException` when accessing list of books. Also i tried manually flushing changes to both repo's and I still get the same exception.

Comment: If you are creating the user instance you must initialize the collection by yourself (`new ArrayList<Book>()` or something like that) what is part of keep the object model consistent.